# Finding the most frequent value by row among n columns in a Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do we find - by row - the most frequent value among 4  two columns in a Spark DataFrame (pyspark 2.2.0)? Example of df:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
13   15   14   14
Null 15   15   13
Null Null Null 13
Null Null Null Null
13   13   14   14
```

My call:

```
df = df.withColumn("frq", \
        most_frequent(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3"),col("col4")) \
        )
```

and the resulting df should be

```
col1 col2 col3 col4  df
13   15   14   14    14
Null 15   15   13    15
Null Null Null 13    13
Null Null Null Null  Null
13   13   14   14    13
```

Note that the Null values should be omited from the calculation even if it's the most frequent value in a row (Null should be returned if all columns are Null though). Tied values (last line in df) can return any of the ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a udf using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf
def mode(*v):
  counter = Counter(x for x in v if x is not None)
  if len(counter) > 0:
    return counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
  else:
    return None

df.withColumn('mode', mode('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')).show()
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|mode|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  13|  15|  14|  14|  14|
|null|  15|  15|  13|  15|
|null|null|null|  13|  13|
|null|null|null|null|null|
|  13|  13|  14|  14|  13|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Helpful, but don't you need to include the actual udf run. i.e. udf_mode = udf(mode)